# Custom converter in ModelMapper not being fired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, modelmapper

I am trying to conver a String to a Date but the converter doesn't seem to be fired and I'm getting a `MappingException`. This is my code:

```
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Converter<String, Date> dateConverter = context -> {
            Date date;
            try {
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(context.getSource());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                date = null;
            }

            System.out.println("working");
            return date;
        };

        modelMapper.addConverter(dateConverter);
        return modelMapper;
    }
```

And then I just use it like this but I continue getting the same error:

```
Date date = this.modelMapper.map("20/12/2019", Date.class);

1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.DateConverter@27c7dc27 failed to convert java.lang.String to java.util.Date.
```

It's not even printing the `working` word.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `Converter`? Which package / import ?

Comment: import org.modelmapper.Converter;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for some reason my dumb IDE (IntelliJ) adviced me to change the code above for how it is in the question. That's what's making it not work, having it as a lambda, it seems. With this code it works perfectly:

```
       Converter<String, Date> dateConverter = new Converter<String, Date>()
        {
            public Date convert(MappingContext<String, Date> context)
            {
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(context.getSource());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }

                return date;
            }
        };
```